# Assembly - Display only uppercase letters

Tags: assembly, dos, masm, x86-16

So what im trying to do is when text in enterd, asdHsExaLzLO and press enter the output shoud be HELLO. But with my current code there is no output. What im doing wrong? I'm trying to store the uppercase letters to OUTPUT but it seems to be not working as i like.

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100H
.DATA
    MSG1 DB 'Enter txt:  $'
    OUTPUT DB '' ;storing uppercase letters
    NEWLINE DB 10, 13, '$'
.CODE
    MAIN PROC
    MOV AX,@DATA ;DS
    MOV DS,AX
    ;print MSG1

    LEA DX,MSG1
    MOV AH,9
    INT 21H


    ; loop  
    loop_top:
    MOV AH,1   ;read input
    INT 21h

    cmp al,0dh  ; check for Enter?
    je Display1  ; if yes,loop goes to display1

    ; Uppercase check
    sub al, 'A'
    cmp al, 'Z'-'A'
    jbe uppercase ;if uppercase go to uppercase 

    uppercase:
    MOV al, OUTPUT  
    jmp loop_top

    loop_end:
    jmp loop_top

    Display1:
    LEA DX, NEWLINE
    MOV AH,09H
    INT 21H

    LEA DX,OUTPUT
    MOV AH,09H
    INT 21H
    jmp exit_program 

    exit_program:
    MOV AH,4CH  ; DOS
    INT 21H

MAIN ENDP
 END MAIN
ENDF
```

Comment: `OUTPUT` has room for just one byte. Plus there's some problems with `mov al, OUTPUT` and `jbe uppercase`. The jump is not needed there as there is no other code between the jump and the label. Did you miss something there `jmp loop_top`?

Comment: @PawełŁukasik: `db ''` is the empty string; that might actually be zero bytes; I'm not sure what MASM or TASM does with that.  But yeah, none of this code stores to OUTPUT, only a load from it, and putting the address into DX before a write-string DOS call.

Comment: It'd be easier to just use the DOS print-character call to go one character at a time, instead of constructing a `$`-terminated string.  You don't have any performance requirement I assume, just that it works, so no need to reduce system call overhead by making just one with a whole buffer.  Although it's probably a better learning exercise if you also learn to filter an array in-place or into a new buffer.